# How to find ratio between specific and total value with annotation in Django and store it in each entity?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I am trying to calculate ratio between sales of each product and total sales. I want to store that ratio in every model entity. How can I do that?

This is my attempt. It doesn't work. It throws "conversion from CombinedExpression to Decimal is not supported".

```
count_products = Product.objects.count() # total value
products = Product.objects.annotate(num_sales=Count('cartitem')).all().annotate(support=Value(F('num_sales') / count_products, output_field=DecimalField()))
```

Comment: Can you explain the model? Your query actually more hints towards *number of items* than *total value*.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `Value` for your division,  it is used only for constants. It should be `.annotate(support=F('num_sales') / count_products)`.  Also I would suggest to add `output_field` into your `Count('cartitem')`, so database will make decimal,  not integer division.  Note that `output_field` must be an instance,  not class itself. So add `()` after `DecimalField`,  it will be enough.